# Triggering and adding event listeners in Office.js dialog box

Tags: javascript, office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins

I want to create an event listener when I open a dialog box. From my taskpane, I open the dialog and send data where I create some elements. The elements need to be controlled by two arrows that let you navigate between them (images in my case).

Here's how I add my event listeners. `slides-container` is the container for all the images I am navigating through and `slide` class is just each image. Both definitely exist and get no errors:

```
Office.onReady((info) => {
  // -----

  Office.context.ui.addHandlerAsync(
    Office.EventType.DialogParentMessageReceived,
    createCarousel,
    onRegisterMessageComplete
  );
}

function createCarousel(args) {
  const results = JSON.parse(args.message);
  // create some elements and populate page

  const slidesContainer = document.querySelector(".slides-container");
  const slideWidth = slidesContainer.querySelector(".slide").clientWidth;
  const prevButton = document.querySelector(".prev");
  const nextButton = document.querySelector(".next");

  nextButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // tried with and without, did not work
    slidesContainer.scrollLeft += slideWidth;
  });

  prevButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    slidesContainer.scrollLeft -= slideWidth;
  });
}
```

I added a console.log inside the callbacks and each event listener was triggered twice for some reason.

I tried the same code in a regular HTML page and it worked. What could be the reason?